# How to allocate a space for a member in a __percpu structure

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I got two structures

```
struct A{
   unsigned long long *c;
};
struct B{
   struct A __percpu *a;
};
```

and the initial part would be

```
struct B *b = kmalloc(sizeof(struct B), GFP_KERNEL);
b->a = alloc_percpu(struct A);
```

now I want to allocate space for c in each a, how could I do that ?

Comment: This might help you: https://lwn.net/Articles/258238/